# Performance issue in SSAS tabular 2017 and 2016 compared to 2014

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular, analysisservices

We are facing performance issue in browsing SSAS tabular (2017 and 2016)cube via excel.

Azure Server Details 2017&2016: Windows server 2016, 128GB RAM, 16 CPU, 64bit, SQL server 2016 developer edition.

But, performance is very good in SSAS tabular 2014 when browsing via excel.

Azure Server Details 2014: Windows server 2012R2, 128GB RAM, 16 CPU, 64bit,  SQL server 2014 developer edition.

e.g: A query provides results in 10 secs in 2014 tabular but, it takes around 5mins in 2016/2017 tabular.

Note:
all tabular settings are set to default in both servers.
compatibility level set : 1103 for 2014 and 1200/1400 for 2016/2017.
Same cube and query is used for test.

Please let us know if you have any inputs.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried setting the compatility level to some lower version for the tabular database? There were major changes made to SSAS in SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Sounds like a support case to me if the perf difference is worthy of that effort